# ESP8266, ESP-01, uploading firmware, module led shine/lights weakly

Tags: led, esp8266, nodemcu

My problem pertains module **ESP8266**, specifically version **ESP-01**.

When I have uploaded firmware (nodemcu) to the module then it works all right.

But later, I found out that the module is not responding. Even after so much restarts. 
In addition, the led on the module shines/ligths very **weakly**.

I don't know where is the problem. Maybe with **power supplying** but I am using usb-to-serial converter which provides 5V as well as 3V. In addition I am using a voltage regulator from 5V to 3.3V because I wanted to be sure.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solving hardware problems is way out of scope for Stack Overflow. Perhaps try electronics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: What if you re-flash it?

Comment: When I have tried re-flash it there was always no response. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that most usb-to-serial interfaces can't provide enough current for the ESP8266 which could draw peak currents of about 320mA. You must use an external power supply.